# Is it possible to use Hadoop MiniCluster without having Hadoop installed locally?

Tags: hadoop, integration-testing, local

Is it possible with [hadoop-mini-cluster](https://github.com/sakserv/hadoop-mini-clusters) or it is just a tool for running cluster locally and it requires to have Hadoop installed on your machine?